# Ant junit run throws Test failed error

Tags: selenium, ant, junit

I am trying to run selenium junit tests using ant in eclipse. Below is my build.xml file and if I run it as a junit test in eclipse, its running fine. But when I run it using ant it's not successful. Build is succesful but the test is failing. Let me know if I am missing anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="runjunit" name="firstbuild">
  <target name="runjunit" depends="compile">
    <junit printsummary="on">
      <test name="com.test.abc"/>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="C:\sample\selenium-2.34.0\selenium-java-2.34.0.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="classes"/>
      </classpath>
    </junit>
  </target>
  <target name="compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src" destdir="classes" classpath="C:\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.10.0.v4_10_0_v20120426-0900\junit.jar;C:\sample\selenium-2.34.0\selenium-java-2.34.0.jar"/>
  </target>
</project>


Buildfile: C:\New folder\workspace\build.xml
compile:
runjunit:
    [junit] Running com.test.abc
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Test com.test.abc FAILED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 409 milliseconds
```

Comment: There's a typo in <pathelement location="clases"/> One 's' is missing in clases.

Comment: I changed to classes and still i see this error.

Comment: Cab you add a `<formatter type="plain" />` element into the current JUnit element, and then give us the output file it produces when run? Ant is detecting an error (i.e. the test has thrown an unexpected exception), and we need to see what it is.